# import excel products in prestashop via xls or csv

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have a question about the importing of products in prestashop:
is it posible to import an xls file and not a csv? because the csv is on a single column and is kind of hard to complete the products..or is it posible to split the csv into more columns like so:

```
column1 | column2 | column 3
id      | name    | category
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Actually CSV has multiple columns; MS Excel just doesn't always undestand the delimiters. For example, when exporting table from database, there is a special option "CSV for Excel". You should experiment with deifferent option when trying to open that file.

Comment: CSV = Comma (,) Separated values, please make sure that's the delimiter you are using so that the file opens correctly